# Is the behavior of Python vs Perl regex for carat and dollar different?

Tags: python, regex, perl

In Python:

Given a string `'ve`, I can catch the start of the string with carat:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = u"'ve"
>>> re.match(u"^[\'][a-z]", s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1109ee030>
```

So it matches even though the length substring after the single quote is > 1.

But for the dollar (matching end of string):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = u"'ve"
>>> re.match(u"[a-z]$", s)
>>>
```

In Perl, from [here](https://github.com/alvations/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/detokenizer.perl#L128)

It seems like the end of string can be matched with:

```
$s =~ /[\p{IsAlnum}]$/
```

Is `$s =~ /[\p{IsAlnum}]$/` the same as `re.match(u"[a-z]$", s)` ?

**Why is the carat and dollar behavior different? And are they different for Python and Perl?**

Comment: It's _caret_ in Python. It's _carat_ in diamond trade.

Comment: @DYZ, lolz carrots.

Comment: `^[\'][a-z]` is better written `^'[a-z]` and `[\p{IsAlnum}]$` is better written `\p{IsAlnum}$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.match` is implicitly anchored at the start of the string. Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

> `re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>
> If zero or more characters at the beginning of `string` match the regular expression `pattern`, return a corresponding `MatchObject` instance.

Try `re.search` instead.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = u"'ve"
>>> re.search(u"[a-z]$", s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fea24df3780>
>>>
```

Comment: Oh Thanks @Rob!! Tricky stuff between `re.search` vs `re.match`.

Comment: Just to be double sure. Is the regex matching in Perl is always the behavior of  `re.search`?

Comment: @alvas Correct. Perl doesn't have a separate operator for matching only at the beginning of a string; for that you use anchors (`\A` or `^`).

Comment: Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot !! BTW, the two of you have helped much in this contribution https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1553